TomSelect not working as expected in Symfony UX
I have a multi-step form implemented using Symfony LiveComponents.
I have multiple forms with ChoiceType's like this:
            ->add('yesOrNo', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => [
                    'label.yes' => true,
                    'label.no' => false,
                ],
                'placeholder' => 'label.choose',
                'label' => 'rnmn.label.yes_or_no',
                'label_translation_parameters' => ['default' => 'Yes or no?'],
                'translation_domain' => 'edesk',
                'autocomplete' => 'on',
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotNull(['message' => new TranslatableMessage('form.error.select-option', ['default' => 'Please select an option.'])]),
                ],
            ]

I use the Flowbite bundle to automatically apply styling to the dropdown, under the hood this is using TomSelect.
The problem is that when I load a LiveComponent, the Javascript is not reloaded and somehow this causes an issue for the dropdown. It automatically disappears after selecting a value.
I applied the following patch from this Github issue:
import { Controller } from '@hotwired/stimulus';
import TomSelect from 'tom-select';
import { getComponent } from '@symfony/ux-live-component';

/* stimulusFetch: 'lazy' */
export default class extends Controller {
    async initialize() {
        this.component = await getComponent(this.element);
        window.addEventListener('select:clear', (event) => {
            var elements = this.element.querySelectorAll('.tomselected');

            elements.forEach(element => {
                if (element.tomselect) {
                    var settings = element.tomselect.settings;
                    element.tomselect.destroy();
                    new TomSelect(element, settings);
                }
            });
        });
    }
}


This kind of works, not the dropdown does not disappear and it nicely updates the value. The problem is that it now automatically submits the form causing the constraint messages to show prematurely.

A form inside a LiveComponent will by default always submit on change to allow for live-validation.
You could add the following Stimulus to your current controller to prevent the auto-submission on change:
connect() {
    this.element.addEventListener('change', this.preventAutoSubmit.bind(this));
}

disconnect() {
    this.element.removeEventListener('change', this.preventAutoSubmit.bind(this));
}

stopAutoSubmit(event) {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
}

